# Group list of records by their attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to list my records grouped by some attribute. For example

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
end
```

Then I want to show all `devices` grouped by `company`, like that:

```
%ul Company 1
  %li Device 1
  %li Device 3
%ul Company 2
  %li Device 2
  %li Device 4
```

The obvious way to do that is query all `companies` and loop through their `devices`, like that:

```
- companies.each do |company|
  %h3= company.title
  %ul
  - company.devices.each do |device|
    %li= device.title
```

But in this case I need to query all `companies` in `DevicesController` and pass them to the view in order to list all `devices`. It feels not natural. 
Is there a better (rails-) way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
includes(:devices)
```

while querying *Company* model

Let us suppose,
In controller,

```
def index
  @companies = Company.last(10).includes(:devices)
end
```

From the above, you will get all associated devices to each specific company object.
Using

> includes(:devices)

will give access to company.devices without firing additional query from view.
You will have performance improvement with a simple join.

Comment: Sure I can do this, but it feel not natural because I have to query `Company` model in order to list `devices`.

Comment: you need not query Company model in order to list devices with includes.You might be thinking company.devices will make a query, but it wont make a query to DB.